# starting jvm subprocess from war web app

Tags: java, war

I've got interesting setup. I have a web app which registers a web service. The web service is essentially a front-end to a buch of classes which do the following:

1. setup an RMI server
2. start a subprocess using the jvm with the specified class in order to do some job

Normally, in order to resolve the classpath I read the System.getProperty("java.class.path"); and I setup this for the -cp parameter. However, with war files, this is useless.

This is how my function which launches a specific class from the classpath looks like:

```
public static Process launchClassProcess(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class c, String[] javaArgs, String[] programArgs) throws Exception {
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String home = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String path = home + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";
    String[] jvmArgs = new String[] { path, "-cp", classpath };
    String[] classArgs = new String[] { c.getName() };
    String[] processBuilderArgs = new String[jvmArgs.length + javaArgs.length + classArgs.length + programArgs.length];
    int i = 0;

    for (String arg:jvmArgs) {
        processBuilderArgs[i++] = arg;
    }

    for (String arg:javaArgs) {
        processBuilderArgs[i++] = arg;
    }

    for (String arg:classArgs) {
        processBuilderArgs[i++] = arg;
    }

    for (String arg:programArgs) {
        processBuilderArgs[i++] = arg;
    }

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(processBuilderArgs);
    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
    int j = 0;

    for (String part:processBuilder.command()) {
        if (j++ != 0) {
            command.append(" ");
        }

        command.append(part);
    }

    LogUtils.recordMessage("executing: " + command.toString());

    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    return (new ProcessBuilder(processBuilderArgs)).start();
}
```

How can I make this function work but with war files? I think that I have to somehow find where my war file has been unpacked on the file system and find the libs folder from which I can build the complete classpath.

Comment: and take care of underlying app server classloading policies. Nice question, looking forward to have some enlightment on this one!

Comment: It is possible to find the file url to any class via the resources. From there we can piggy back to the top the root of the class in order to find where the jar is and register everything underneath that as classpath. However, this is a bit insecure as one can imagine. If it is possible to detect somehow if we are currently executing inside a web app .. that will minimize the risk significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to add a bit of magic which modifies the classpath in order to make the above function work.

We need the following servlet, let's call it InitServlet

```
public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        String libRealPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/lib/");

        if (libRealPath == null) {
            throw new ServletException("cannot find web-inf lib path");
        }

        ArrayList<String> libs = new ArrayList<String>();
        File libDir = new File(libRealPath);

        for (String file:libDir.list(new FilenameFilter() {

            public boolean accept(File dir, String file) {
                return file.endsWith(".jar");
            }

        })) {
            libs.add(libRealPath + System.getProperty("file.separator") + file);
        }

        System.setProperty("java.class.path", System.getProperty("java.class.path") + System.getProperty("path.separator") + ProcessUtils.joinPaths(libs));
    }

}
```

Then, we need to register the servlet in web.xml to do the magic:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>init-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>InitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the lib folder from a ServletContext:

```
ServletContext context = ....;
Set< String > libs = context.getResourcePaths( "/WEB-INF/lib" );
```